# How to know the version number of docutils

Tags: docutils

I found myself searching for the version of docutils the server was running. To my surprise, it wasn't as straight forward as typing whatever command with flag "--version". I finally got it through the commands below, but isn't it something more direct than that?

```
# Assuming we are on Debian like distribution
aptitude show python-docutils

# If "docutils" is managed by pip
pip freeze | grep docutils
```

Answer (score 1):

The Docutils package (like many other Python packages) exposes a version number through the parameter `__version__` (search for this in `/path/to/docutils/__init__.py` for the definition/documentation). A simple one liner to display this is:

```
python -c "import docutils; print docutils.__version__"
```

**Edit**: Having just tried `python rst2html.py --version` I get the following information printed to screen

> rst2html.py (Docutils 0.9.1 [release], Python 2.6.8, on linux2)

is this what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Since release 0.19 (2022-07-05), the docutils package comes with the
"docutils" CLI front end, so you can just open a terminal and type

```
 docutils --version
```

(Other front end tools like `rst2html5` come with the `--version` command line option, too.)

If the "docutils" package was installed with `pip`, the command

```
 pip show docutils
```

includes the version in the displayed info.